# How to join nearly identical several queries into one?

Tags: sql, mysql

Assume I have an `order_dummy` table where `order_dummy_id, order_id, user_id, book_id, author_id` are stored. You may complain the logic of my table but I somehow need to do it that way. I want to execute following queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_dummy
WHERE order_id = 1
AND user_id = 1
AND book_id = 1
ORDER BY `order_dummy_id` DESC
LIMIT 1

SELECT * 
FROM order_dummy
WHERE order_id = 1
AND user_id = 1
AND book_id = 2
ORDER BY `order_dummy_id` DESC
LIMIT 1

SELECT * 
FROM order_dummy
WHERE order_id = 1
AND user_id = 1
AND book_id = 3
ORDER BY `order_dummy_id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Please keep in mind that several numbers of same book is included in one order. Therefore, I list `order_dummy_id` by descending and limit `1` so only LATEST ORDER of A BOOK is shown. But my goal is to show other books in that way in one table. I used `group by` like this ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_dummy
WHERE order_id = 1
AND user_id = 1
GROUP BY book_id
```

but it only shows `order_dummy_id` with ascending result. I have no idea anymore. Looking forward your kindness help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the results of multiple selects in one go use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM order_dummy
    WHERE order_id = 1
    AND user_id = 1
    AND book_id = 1
    ORDER BY `order_dummy_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM order_dummy
    WHERE order_id = 1
    AND user_id = 1
    AND book_id = 2
    ORDER BY `order_dummy_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM order_dummy
    WHERE order_id = 1
    AND user_id = 1
    AND book_id = 3
    ORDER BY `order_dummy_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Is that efficient if I want to union above 16 queries?

Comment: @Devyn: This query will be very efficient if you have an index on (order_id, user_id, book_id, order_dummy_id). But it is a very ugly query. Is performance or readability/maintainablity the most important aspect in deciding which query to use?

Comment: I really have no other way :( I've tried as far as I can. I may change that query in the future but I must step forward to finish my project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the relationship between your tables. 
book id should not be in order row since we can have multiple books per order. You need to have a table called "ordered items" and store your books there along with ordered quantity - no need for multiple rows.

To answer your question, I can point you to SQL operator `IN`:

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3)
```

Also, depending on the context you can use OR operator

```
select * from table where id = 1 or id = 2 or id =3
```

Comment: @abatishchev please do not edit my English. Normalise is British spelling which I use living in UK. Normalize is American!